# Найти имя объекта в котором в паре ключ:значенение в значении указана некоторая иноформация

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Есть словарь с подобным содержанием:

```
json
{
    'users': {
        '76561199129019742': {
            'AccountName': 'cfaxxpswwc57y',
            'PersonaName': 'SemDesonLon',
            'RememberPassword': '0',
            'MostRecent': '0',
            'Timestamp': '1618041785'
        },
        '76561199128794854': {
            'AccountName': 'utzmgfyb7snim',
            'PersonaName': 'SemDesonLon',
            'RememberPassword': '0',
            'MostRecent': '0',
            'Timestamp': '1618041785'
        }
    }
}
```

Есть значение AccountName, по которому нужно найти имя объекта в котором оно находится. Как это сделать в Python?

Пример:

Из этого `cfaxxpswwc57y`

Получить это `76561199129019742`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
users = {
    '76561199129019742': {
        'AccountName': 'cfaxxpswwc57y',
    },
    '76561199128794854': {
        'AccountName': 'utzmgfyb7snim',
    }
}

def get_key_by_name(name):
    for key, obj in users.items():
        if obj['AccountName'] == name:
            return key

    return None

print( get_dict_by_name('cfaxxpswwc57y') ) # '76561199129019742'
```

Если это частая операция, можно создать вспомогательный словарь вида

```
'cfaxxpswwc57y': '76561199129019742',
'utzmgfyb7snim': '76561199128794854',
```

```
users = {
    '76561199129019742': {
        'AccountName': 'cfaxxpswwc57y',
    },
    '76561199128794854': {
        'AccountName': 'utzmgfyb7snim',
    }
}

keys = { val['AccountName']: key for key, val in users.items() }

def get_key_by_name(name):
    return keys.get(name) # Вторым параметром можно указать значение по умолчанию.
                          # В таком виде вернется None, если ключ не найден.

print( get_key_by_name('cfaxxpswwc57y') ) # '76561199129019742'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {
    'users': {
        '76561199129019742': {
            'AccountName': 'cfaxxpswwc57y',
            'PersonaName': 'SemDesonLon',
            'RememberPassword': '0',
            'MostRecent': '0',
            'Timestamp': '1618041785'
        },
        '76561199128794854': {
            'AccountName': 'utzmgfyb7snim',
            'PersonaName': 'SemDesonLon',
            'RememberPassword': '0',
            'MostRecent': '0',
            'Timestamp': '1618041785'
        }
    }
}
name = input() 
for x in dict['users']:
    if name == dict['users'][x]['AccountName']:
        object = dict['users'][x]
        print(object)
```